# Roll up Summary via trigger for lookup relationship

Tags: apex, trigger, class, lookup, roll-up-summary

I am trying to get this trigger to work but it is giving me an error and I am not able to figure out why. The error I am getting is "attempt to de-reference a null object)

Why trigger? We have a Destinations object which is linked to Supplier products object via a lookup relationship. There are two types of supplier products(marketplace and curated) We want to count the number of live Supplier products and put them in a separate fields(live counts for each type).

I have gotten so far to actually count the number of live products and it is giving me an error. Can any one help? I am posting the code below

**Trigger code :**

```
trigger NoOfLiveProducts on Supplier_Product__c (after insert, after Delete, after update, after undelete) {


    set<string> destinationids = new set<string>();

    if(trigger.isInsert) {
        for(Supplier_product__c products : Trigger.new) {
            destinationids.add(products.Destination__c);
        }
    } else if(trigger.isDelete) {
        for(Supplier_product__c products : Trigger.old) {
            destinationids.add(products.Destination__c);
        }
    }else if(trigger.isUnDelete) {
        for(Supplier_product__c products : Trigger.new){
            destinationids.add(products.Destination__c);
        }

    } else if(trigger.isUpdate) {
        for(Supplier_product__c products : Trigger.new) {
            destinationids.add(products.Destination__c);
        }
    }

    if(destinationids.size() > 0){
        Productcounter pc = new Productcounter();
        pc.updateproductCount(destinationids);
    }



}
```

**Class code :**

```
public class Productcounter {

    public void updateproductcount(set<string> productIDs) {

         if(productIDs == null){   
            return;
        }

        if(productIDs.size() == 0){
            return;
        }

         list<Supplier_Product__c> ProductList = new list<Supplier_Product__c>();
        ProductList = [Select ID,Destination__c
                    From Supplier_Product__c
                    Where Destination__c = :productIDs];

        integer totalCount;
        map<string, integer> DestinationIDToProductCountMap = new map<string, integer>();       
        for(Supplier_product__c ProductItem : ProductList){
            if(DestinationIDToProductCountMap.containsKey(ProductItem.Destination__c)){
                totalCount = DestinationIDToProductCountMap.get(ProductItem.Destination__c);
            }else{
                totalCount = 0;
            }
            totalCount += 1;
            DestinationIDToProductCountMap.put(ProductItem.Destination__c, totalCount);
        }

        list<Destination__c> DestinationUpdateList = new list<Destination__c>();
        Destination__c DestinationTemp;
        for(string ProductID : DestinationIDToProductCountMap.keySet()){
            DestinationTemp.ID = ProductID;
            DestinationTemp.No_of_Live_Curated_Products__c = DestinationIDToProductCountMap.get(ProductID);
            DestinationUpdateList.add(DestinationTemp);
        }
        if(DestinationUpdateList.size() > 0){
            update DestinationUpdateList;
        }

         }

         }
```

Comment: for future reference, the free package 'Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary (DLRS)' by Andrew Fawcett can solve these kinds of problems in a point-and-click manner

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work because it has to count the number of records and it is not rolling up a particular field. I have run into another problem here. Can you help?

Comment: did the @sfdcfox solution not work for you? He's invariably accurate

Comment: That worked but I need to segment the number of live products based on a picklist field called "type"(curated and marketplace) on the object "Supplier Products". At the moment, I am counting all the products(curated and marketplace) and throwing it into one.

Comment: Here is my new code that I used, I have posted it in chunks
trigger NoOfLiveProducts on Supplier_Product__c (after insert, after Delete, after update) {
 
    Set<id> destinationIds = new Set<id>();
    List<Destination__c> destinationsToUpdate = new List<Destination__c>();

    for (Supplier_Product__c item : Trigger.new)
        destinationIds.add(item.Destination__c);

    if (Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isDelete) {
        for (Supplier_Product__c item : Trigger.old)
            destinationIds.add(item.Destination__c);
    }
    System.debug('>>>>destinationIds>>>>'+destinationIds);

Comment: Map<id,Destination__c> destinationMap = new Map<id,Destination__c>([select id, No_of_Live_Curated_Products__c from Destination__c where id IN :destinationIds]);
 
    for (Destination__c dest : [select Id, Name, No_of_Live_Curated_Products__c,(select id from Supplier_Products__r) from Destination__c where Id IN :destinationIds]) {
        destinationMap.get(dest.Id).No_of_Live_Curated_Products__c = dest.Supplier_Products__r.size();
         
        destinationsToUpdate.add(destinationMap.get(dest.Id));
    }
    update destinationsToUpdate; 
    
}
@sfdcfox, please help if you can

Comment: Dev -- you should mark @sfdcfox's answer as the solution and then post a brand new question - it gets too confusing for us here to deal with follow-on questions within the same thread

Comment: @Dev I'll take a look at your new question, by the way. It's just hard to read code in comments. You're on the right track, but I have a feeling you got "lost" somewhere. I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code returns a null pointer exception because you never assigned a value to DestinationTemp before attempting to reference it (the ID field).

You'd want to do this:

```
for(...
    DestinationTemp = new Destination__c();
    DestinationTemp.Id = ProductId;
    ...
```

Also, some tips for the future:

If your Destination__c can change, you should use a simpler Trigger.new/Trigger.old approach:

```
if(Trigger.old != null) {
    for(Supplier_Product__c record: Trigger.old) {
        destinationIds.add(record.Destination__c);
    }
}
if(Trigger.new != null) {
    for(Supplier_Product__c record: Trigger.new) {
        destinationIds.add(record.Destination__c);
    }
}
```

This handles the situation where a destination might change because of a field edit. Even if you *don't* allow that change, this code is still more efficient to cover than your original code.

Do not check for nulls that cannot happen. Your function is called with a value that is never null, but you check anyways:

```
if(productIDs == null){   
        return;
    }
```

Further, your code checks to see if that list is empty... TWICE!

```
if(destinationids.size() > 0){ 

if(productIDs.size() == 0){
```

Also, assuming Destination__c is a required field, size() will never, ever be empty. I guarantee it. You can remove all those checks and save time, increase code coverage, etc.

Next, you could be using an aggregate result query:

```
AggregateResult[] sums = [SELECT Count(Id), Destination__c FROM Supplier_Product__c WHERE Destination__c IN :productIds GROUP BY Destination__c];
```

All you need to do then is make a simple Map to update the destinations:

```
Map<Id, Destination__c> destinations = new Map<Id, Destination__c>();
for(Id productId: productIds) {
    destinations.put(productId, new Destination__c(Id=productId, No_of_Live_Curated_Products__c=0.0));
}
for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT Count(Id) total, Destination__c Id FROM Supplier_Product__c WHERE Destination__c IN :productIds GROUP BY Destination__c]) {
    destinations.get((Id)result.get('Id')).No_of_Live_Curated_Products__c = (Decimal)result.get('total');
}
update destination.values();
```

Also, as ProductIds is never, ever empty, the DML statement will also never be empty...

Next, don't make instances when you could be using static functions:

```
ProductCounter.updateProductCount(productIds);

...

public static void updateProductCount(Set<Id> productIds) { ...
```

Finally, you really should be using an ID type when the type is ID, not String. This makes it clear to readers that the values are obviously ID values, not some other value like, say, the name of a record or something.

```
Set<Id> productIds = new Set<Id>();
...
```

---

```
trigger NoOfLiveProducts on Supplier_Product__c (after insert, after Delete, after update, after undelete) {
    set<id> destinationids = new set<id>();
    if(trigger.new != null) {
        for(Supplier_product__c products : Trigger.new) {
            destinationids.add(products.Destination__c);
        }
    }
    if(trigger.old != null) {
        for(Supplier_product__c products : Trigger.old) {
            destinationids.add(products.Destination__c);
        }
    }
    ProductCounter.updateproductCount(destinationids);
}
```

---

```
public class Productcounter {
    public void updateproductcount(set<id> productIDs) {
        Map<Id, Destination__c> destinations = new Map<Id, Destination__c>();
        for(Id productId: productIds) {
            destinations.put(productId, new Destination__c(Id=productId, No_of_Live_Curated_Products__c=0.0));
        }
        for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT Count(Id) total, Destination__c Id FROM Supplier_Product__c WHERE Destination__c IN :productIds GROUP BY Destination__c]) {
            destinations.get((Id)result.get('Id')).No_of_Live_Curated_Products__c = (Decimal)result.get('total');
        }
        update destination.values();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the error now stating that there is no field called "total" in the query aggregate result query. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dev I actually forgot that it needed to be `Count(Id)` instead of just `Count()`. The message you'd get is if you didn't alias the Count(Id) function... I've just made an edit, so take a peek.

Comment: I used a different code than you suggested. Can you please look at comments above and help me please. I have posted the code and comments above in another comment. Please have a look if you can. thanks