# How to handle Roll Up Summary type Calculations WITHOUT using Master-Detail

Tags: master-detail, roll-up-summary

I currently have an object called `Opportunities__c` with a child object related to it, `Opportunities_Forecast__c` via a Master-Detail relationship. The `Forecast__c` object contains two number fields that ultimately get summed up using a Roll-Up Summary field on the `Opportunities__c` object.

The nature of the object needs to change now in that `Opportunities_Forecast__c` is just a general forecasting object and could be related to the `Account` object or `Opportunities__c` object, thus it may not *always* have a relationship to an `Opportunity__c` record. I know Master-Detail fields are required on child objects, so I have to change the data type to a Lookup.

I can't do this (yet) because of the Roll-Up summary fields. So, I was wondering what the best way to handle the functionality of Roll-Up summary fields, without them being Roll-Up summary fields.

One idea I had was to use a Trigger that would check for Create, Update and Delete events and recalculate the fields accordingly, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Write `Apex Trigger` to calculate the summed up value. The trigger context will be on insert, update and delete.

Comment: @RCS This is an idea I already had, although I'm curious to know if there's a better way of doing it rather than just throwing Apex at it I suppose.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way to do this would be using a trigger as you've anticipated. I would strongly recommend using a lib like this: https://github.com/abhinavguptas/Salesforce-Lookup-Rollup-Summaries so you don't have to build it all by yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard go-to answer is to use Andrew Fawcett's excellent [Declarative Rollup Summary](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) package. There's a managed package install link, and it comes complete with a UI for configuring your desired rollups. It works on any object that supports custom fields and triggers, so give it a go! Also, it's open source, so you can borrow bits and pieces if you decide to give it a go yourself. Finally, this has definitely been answered here on [SFSE before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=roll+up+summary+trigger), including an [answer of my own](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81688). The actual implementation is pretty trivial when you get down to it, but you do need to pay attention to the details.

Comment: Thanks for this, looks like I'm writing a Trigger! I'd prefer that to installing a package. @RobCowell I wanted to avoid using Apex Triggers, although I'd prefer to write Apex than install a managed package by preference. I think Mr. Fox is alluding to questions around writing an Apex Trigger for this functionality, whereas this is asking if there's declarative workarounds, which there is, but not quite what I was hoping for. :)

Comment: @DanJones Yes, unfortunately triggers is the only option. The newer features like Process Builder don't work on deletes, so they can't keep your data in sync. If you absolutely need correct data, you absolutely need a trigger.

Comment: @sfdcfox That's perfectly fine and I'm comfortable with writing that. My mentality here is 90% Clicks before Code, 10% laziness. ;D

Answer (score 0):

You are right, a trigger is the best Solution.

You will need to have a trigger that maps and groups all children by parent.
So you can iterate across the parents children.
Not tested Psuedo Code:

```
trigger(After Insert/Update){
    map<id, list<child>> parentChild_Map = new map<id, list<child>>();
    map<id,parent> parent_Map = new map<id,parent>();
    set<id> parent_Set = new set<id>();
    set<id> parent_Set2 = new set<id>();

    for(children c : trigger.new){
        parent_Set.add(c.parentId);
    }
    parent_Map = [SELECT id, sum__c FROM Parent WHERE Id IN parent_Set];
    children_List = [SELECT id, parentid, value__c FROM child WHERE parentId IN parent_Set];

    for(child c : children_List){
        if(parent_Set2.contains(c.parentId)) {
           parent_map.get(p.ParentId).sum__c = parent_map.get(p.ParentId).sum__c + c.value__c;
        else{
           parent_Set2.add(c.ParentId);
           parent_map.get(c.ParentId).sum__c = c.value__c;
        }
    }

    update parent_map.values();
}
```